# Image segmentation in python (opencv) - Insect wing

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, edge-detection, binary-image

This is the kind of image that I have:
[image]

Another example:
[image]

now the ground truth:
[image]
[image]

I need a code to get the results similar to the ground truth algorithm, any idea and suggestion will help me because I don't even know where to start, thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please edit the code you have tried into your question and show the results you have achieved, and make clear what is wrong/inadequate about these results.

Comment: Were the ‘ground truth’ images actually created from these noisy jpeg source images?

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Load image in grayscale
img = cv.imread('coins.png',0)

# threshold the image
thresh = cv.threshold(img,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# display the image
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
plt.show()
```

refer this [example](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html)

Comment: So what output does your code produce from the example source images the OP provided?